# How to access hostname tags in ansible playbook based on aws ec2 inventory hostname's ip addresses?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I am using aws ec2 plugin in ansible 2.9. I would like to connect to aws ec2 instances with private ip address but in my playbook, I want to display other hostname tags such as hostname and region along with corresponding private ip addresses. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this within the playbook?

Here is my ec2 inventory:
testall.aws_ec2.yml

```
plugin: aws_ec2

hostnames:
       - tag:Name
       - tag: Region
       - private-ip-address
compose:
  ansible_host: private_ip_address
```

And here is what I have in my playbook:

```
test-playbook.yml 
---
- hosts:  "{{ variable_host | default('test')}}"
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
      - debug: 
               msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"

...
```

I run my playbook as follows:

```
ansible-playbook -i testall.aws_ec2.yml test-playbook.yml --extra-vars variable_host=testall
```

However, my playbook returns only the tag:Name (the first item specified in hostnames in inventory):

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************
ok: [test-abc-host1]
ok: [test-abc-host2]
```

Comment: This is the fact gathering, you should at least have something coming out of your debug or an error. Then it should end with a recap. Please show us the full result of your playbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first match is used for `inventory_hostname` where the value of `hostnames` arg is a list in descending order of precedence.

From `ansible-doc --type inventory amazon.aws.aws_ec2`:

```
hostnames:
      description:
          - A list in order of precedence for hostname variables.
          - You can use the options specified in U(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html#options).
          - To use tags as hostnames use the syntax tag:Name=Value to use the hostname Name_Value, or tag:Name to use the value of the Name tag.
      type: list
      default: []
```

You could find [further attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html#options) for each inventory host with the module `ec2_metadata_facts`.

`ansible-doc amazon.aws.ec2_metadata_facts`